# Node.js - Plutus/Haskell Wrapper

Tags: plutus, smart-contract

Do you think a Node.js/JavaScript Wrapper for the Plutus programming language (I think it was Haskell?) is possible? This would bring millions of developers onto the Cardano ecosystem and their smart contracts.

I'm not that deep in the blockchain world, so I'm just wondering if this is technically possible.

Answer (score 4):

Technically it should be possible once the IELE virtual machine is finished. Currently it is still under R&D.

Once complete, we should be able to run code from any platform/framework inside the virtual machine if the appropriate conversion tools are also built.

Comment: If my understanding is right, this works only for sidechains. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe someone else can confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you could develop a new compiler that compiles from a different language into Plutus Core (see [Plutus Tx: compiling Haskell into Plutus Core](https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2021/02/02/plutus-tx-compiling-haskell-into-plutus-core/)).
Additionally, you would need a different (not Haskell-based) client that could create transactions and publish them to the blockchain. But also a simple wrapper that is still based on Haskell but would wrap foreign Plutus Core code could also work.

Answer (score 0):

Project catalyst has a few guys building a Ouroborus Networking package for JavaScript.. it’s coming.

https://twitter.com/cardanomint/status/1397223641222369285?s=21

Answer (score 0):

The choice of Haskell based Plutus was deliberate to create a "Formally verifiable Secure" smart contract.

A smart contract becomes useless once bugs are discovered in some layer every year. To be recognised as a dependable platform with a larger scope and mainstream adaptation Formal methods supported by math were a critical requirement.

Therefore, there is a school of thought that developers who can learn and write "Secure Contract" will be more valuable and dependable. However, for fun applications where security is not a major constraint wrapper are also being developed. As it can be appreciated I guess Plutus is being prioritised to bring in "Secure" Contract.